Positioning the r scale on the left side on a polar graph with Gnuplot 5.4 and minor details
I need help to get:

A logarithmic radial scale positioned on the left side of the graph;
Reduce the font size of the theta scale (degrees);
Position the legend at the bottom of the graph and reduce the font size to improve graph visibility

=====
Problem description:
I've been trying to position the scale on the left side of a polar plot in Gnuplot 5.4 without success. The image I should be able to produce is something like this:

The best I could do was:

The code and most important data file to plot are below:
 set size square
 set angles degrees
 set polar
 set ttics 0,10
 set ttics norotate offset 1
 set theta clockwise right
 set mttics 3
 unset xtics
 unset ytics
 set grid polar 10. lt -1 dt 0 lw 0.5
 set border 0
 unset param
 set title ''
 set xlabel ''
 set ylabel ''
 set style data line
 set logscale r
 set rrange [1.0E-4:1.0E+1]
 set trange [0.0E+0:3.6E+2]
plot  'out.txt' using 1:2 title 'Reflectancia' with lines
replot 'out.txt' using 1:3 title 'Transmitancia' with lineslines


=====
Thank you very much for your attention.

Here is my suggestion:

probably the simplest way to add some other axes is to use multiplot (check help multiplot), but then you have to care about the margins, origins and sizes of the plots. Furthermore, since the logscale is from 1 to 1e-5 and to 1 again, you probably have to use two plots to create such an axis.

check help ttics or since the information is missing there, better help xtics. Something like: set ttics font ",10"

check help key. Something like set key right at screen 0.99, 0.2 box font ",10"


Trying with set logscale r, I did not succeed with the alignment of the margins. Hence, in the script below I'm not using radial logscale, but plotting the data using log10() and rrange[-5:0].
Since I don't have your data, the scripts creates some test data and for simplicity uses it twice.
Script:
### special radial plot with extra axis
reset session
set angles degrees

# create some test data
set table $Data
    set samples 50
    f(x) = cos(x)>0 ? 0.1/(acos(cos(x))) : NaN
    g(x) = cos(x)<0 ? 0.01 : NaN
    plot [0.1:359.9] '+' u 1:(f(x)):(g(x)) w table
unset table

set size square
unset tics
set polar
set border 0 polar
set grid polar lt 0 lc "black" lw 1.0
set margins 0,0,0,0

set rrange [-5:0] 
set format r ''
set rtics 1 scale 0
unset raxis

set trange [0:360]
set theta ccw right
set ttics 0,10 norotate in offset 0.0 font ",10"
set mttics 3

tm = 0.07           # top margin (in screen coordinates)
bm = 0.07           # bottom margin
h0 = 1.0 - tm - bm  # height
lm = 0.15           # left margin
set size 1,h0
set origin 0,bm
set clip polar
set key right at screen 0.99, 0.2 box font ",10"

set multiplot

    plot $Data u 1:(log10($2)) w l ti "Reflectancia", \
            '' u 1:(log10($3)) w l ti "Transmitancia", \
            '' u 1:(log10($2)) w p ti "experimental", \
            '' u 1:(log10($3)) w p ti "direto"

    unset polar
    set size nosquare
    set border 2
    set logscale y
    set ytics nomirror
    unset grid
    set format y "10^{%T}"
    
    set yrange[1:1e-5]
    set origin lm,bm
    set size 0.5,h0/2
    plot NaN notitle

    set yrange[1e-5:1]
    set origin lm,bm+h0/2
    plot NaN notitle

unset multiplot
### end of script

Result:


I would like to thank you for your help. I implemented your suggestion, but the graph does not display correctly. I think this is because I was unable to send you the table with the data... Notice how the algorithm you recommended seems to smooth my experimental data:
based on your code:

In the end, I ended up implementing a similar code, but using the logarithmic scale on the r-axis.
combined code:

My idea is to add the angles with a figure in Powerpoint.

Glad to hear that my suggestion was helpful. But are you sure that you replaced in my code $Data with your filename? That's why it's good to add original test data. So, please share the code which solved your problem that others can learn from it. And then accept your own answer for not letting this question appear unsolved. Well, adding angles in Powerpoint I would consider pretty painful, I would prefer to do it right and right away in gnuplot.

You are correct, theozh.
The code I used is shown below. I couldn't add the txt files, sorry...
### special radial plot with extra axis
reset session
set angles degrees
set size square
unset tics
set polar
set border 0 polar
set grid polar lt 0 lc "black" lw 1.0
set margins 0,0,0,0
set rrange [1.0E-5:5.0E+0]
set logscale r
set format r ''
set rtics 1 scale 0
unset raxis
unset raxis
set key font ",5"
set key spacing 0.5
set key top right
set trange [0.0E+0:3.6E+2]
set theta ccw right
set ttics 0,10 norotate in offset 0.0 font ",5"
set mttics 3
tm = 0.07
bm = 0.07
h0 = 1.0 - tm - bm
lm = 0.15
set size 1, h0
set origin 0, bm
set clip polar
set key right at screen 0.99, 0.2 box font ",5"
set multiplot
plot 'saida.txt' using 1:2 title 'reflec.' with     , \
'saida.txt' using 1:3 title 'transm.' with lines, \
'experimental.txt' using 1:2 title 'exper.' with points, \
'direto.txt' using 1:2 title 'direto' with points
unset polar
set size nosquare
set border 2
set logscale y
set ytics nomirror font ",5"
unset grid
set format y "10^{%T}"
set yrange [5.0E+0:1.0E-5]
set origin lm,bm
set size 0.5,h0/2
plot NaN notitle
set yrange [1.0E-5:5.0E+0]
set origin lm,bm+h0/2
plot NaN notitle
unset multiplot
pause -1
### end of script

The only problem that remains is that some charts display the azimuthal and radial scales and others don't. I think it's because of the magnitude of the data... but honestly, I've spent a lot more time trying to fix these errors.
Case that worked well
case supposedly works
